# show chart when form load without getting data

Tags: c#, charts

I need a chart on my application, I have to bind it to a column table when a button click to get value based on a text box. but when form is loaded my chart area is blank without no columns that it is not nice. how can I show chart on my form even when it does not get its proper data?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - For a Winforms application use the MSCHhart control from the data tab!.

Comment: @TaW sorry for tagging in a bad way, I use Winforms and MSchart. but I have a problem that describe it.

Comment: _but I have a problem that describe it._Well, maybe you have a problem and maybe you don't. But you surely didn't properly `describe' your problem. To wit: Charts show up empty without datapoints; to avoid that you can indeed create a dummy series with one transparent dummy point as the answer suggests.. Call it 'No data' and hide/disable it after the data are loaded and bound!

Comment: @Taw Thank you. yeah now you get my point and I can make a good conclusion with your help and jomasdf and creat a dummy series.

Answer (score 0):

How about just loading it with dummy data on form load? You could keep that on another chart and then remove it when the data fills up the other chart.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. It came to my mind too but I thought there would be a better solution.

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with it as long as it looks smooth. You could even do the same exept for with a pictureBox with whatever indicator you want.